# Centrifugal force vs reactive centrifugal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

After reading (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_centrifugal_force) (especially third paragraph of the introduction) and comparing it with the answer by Bob Jacobsen posted here ([Why does a rotating non-rigid object elongate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/529904/)), I cannot make the statements agree with each other. My question is:

Are the centripetal force and the reactive centrifugal force also present in the rotating frame? I would guess so as the rotating object needs to be hold in place (applies to any frame). But additionally, there is now this "fictitious" centrifugal force, which causes the elongation of non-rigid objects, right?

Answer (score 1):

Centrifugal force is a pseudo-force that only exists in the non-inertial (rotating) frame. For example when your car takes a sharp turn, you feel an outwards force although it seems like nothing is causing it. It is added to explain the apparent outwards force and make sure that Newton's laws remain valid. The centripetal force exists in both reference frames as it is a 'true force' and is the reason why the object is rotating. However to you **inside** the car, you will only experience the centrifugal force.

Comment: Thanks, wouldn’t that mean the wikipedia article is wrong, at least the third paragraph of the introduction?

Comment: The mentioned wikipedia article is correct. I have changed the wording a bit. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I cannot see the changes you made. Could it because the changes haven‘t yet been validated by other wikipedia authors? I am not sure...still, this third paragraph in the introduction causes me headache. It says that the fictitious centrifugal force only exists in the rotating frame in addition to the reactive force, which can be assumed to be the reactive centrifugal force that counteracts the centripetal force. So if the the latter only exists in the inertial frame, so must the reactive centrifugal force only exist in the inertial frame. „in addition“ makes no sense to me...

Comment: No, I meant that I changed the wording of **my** answer. The wikipedia paragraph was correct in itself. The centrifugal force counteracts the centripetal force only in the rotating frame. Hence the body is at rest in the rotating frame. In the inertial frame, only centripetal force exists and hence the body is in rotational motion.

Comment: Thanks Sam, but it is still not clear, unfortunately. What is about the „reactive“ centrifugal force? If the „fictitious“ centrifugal force were to counteract the centripetal force and there were no „reactive“ centrifugal force, then the sum of forces in radial direction would be 0. The wikipedia article says that all three forces are present in rotating frame, at least I understand it that way. Am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: The fictious centrifugal force and the reactive centrifugal forces are the same! They are just different adjectives used to describe the same force. 'fictious' because it is not supposed to exist and 'reactive' because it opposes the centripetal force. We are only talking about two forces in this entire problem.

Comment: Ok, let suppose these two centrifugal forces are the same. How can it be that in the rotating frame the centrifugal force causes elongation of a rod if it just counteract the centripetal force. A resultant force would be needed to cause the change in length, isn‘t it?

Comment: That is because for a rod of uniform density, tension varies along the length. So a part of the rod at a distance $x$ from the end of the rod experiences different magnitudes of tension and centripetal force. Hence there is net force causing the increase in length.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but when at each $x$ the centripetal force and the centrifugal force are the same, how is that possible? Both forces only depends on the radius, when a homogenous mass distribution is assumed. Obviously, when somewhere a part of the rod of length dx is cut out, the centripetal and centrifugal forces are the same for the same surface. The difference in forces between the two surface in direction of the longitudinal axis is  +m*dx*omega^2 for centripetal force and -m*dx*omega^2 for the centrifugal force.

Comment: No, the tension and centripetal force will be different at each point. The calculation is a bit tricky but the tension comes out to be $T=\frac {1}{2L} M\omega^2(L^2-x^2)$. The centripetal force will be $F=M\omega^2x$

Comment: Sam, I really appreciate your help, but I think I need to read a bit more about it in a good textbook. The textbooks I have found didn‘t really provide a good explanation and some were actually misleading. I wonder why this basic topic is so widely taught insufficiently and wrongly. Do you have a good textbook in mind, which explains this topic well and in detail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104242/discussion-between-sam-and-exorbitant).